# How do I fix a car door that is wavy along the edges and has weird textures

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

I am a newbie to Blender and I am making trying to make a car for my second project. I really don't know how I'm going to make the car door look right. It is physically wavy and not straight along it's edges and the window also has flawed texturing. Think coloring outside the lines, that is basically what it looks like. It also has some lump of car door materials on it.

Here's the link for the .blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ow57h42HAXOqnergJRW6F-XNVzlggGc4/view?usp=sharing

[image: Door from the side.]

[image: Door from the side in Edit Mode.]

[image: Door from the front.]

Comment: Your topology is bad. Read up on proper edge flow, use only quads, don't converge to too many poles, keep the face size consistent. [[good topology guide](http://topologyguides.com/)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The waviness seems to be a result of a subsurf modifier. The easiest way to handle this is to simply double up the edges along the border. This should make it appear as a hard edge, eliminating the ripples where the faces are subdivided and averaged into the places you don't want them.